# How can I randomly instance and distribute objects from a collection on a mesh using Animation Nodes?

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I would like to know couple possible ways of taking objects (couple or all) from a collection randomly and instance on a given mesh. I tried feeding the collection into a loop and repositioning them to the given vert list, which works but that just manipulates my collection items and I cant seem to find a way to create many instances and position them inside a loop.

Thanks
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Mesh Point Scatter` and `Object Instancer` node we can scatter objects on the surface of given mesh. Since Object Instancer node cannot be used inside Loop we can't randomize objects. One solution for this problem is by replacing instanced object with other object data(random objects data from collection). For that we can use `Copy Object Data` node.

[image]